# How to make sympy print O(2**n) instead of O(exp(n*log(2)))

Tags: python, big-o, sympy

I'm using `SymPy order` library trying something and discover the follow equation:

```
O(2**n, (n, oo))
```

output will be `O(exp(n*log(2)))`.

Is there any way to make SymPy output `O(2**n)` instead of `O(exp(n*log(2)))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fake it with

```
>>> o = O(2**n, (n, oo))
>>> Function("O")(*map(simplify,o.args))
O(2**n, (n, oo))
```

But if you want to be able to print it this way it looks like you would have to create a custom printer to allow it to be printed that way. If you do `o.func(*map(...))` -- even with `evaluate=False` -- it reverts back to the `exp` form so this appears to be hardcoded into the way that `O` wants to show things. It might be worth raising an issue as to whether an `evaluate` keyword should be added/obeyed with O.